# Invalid x-ms-version header in Azure PHP SDK with blob storage

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I set up a container in Azure to store blob objects. When using `createBlockBlob` method within the Azure PHP SDK I receive the following error output:

`400: Fail:
Code: 400
Value: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
details (if any): ﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:
Time:2016-02-18T14:33:05.9196494Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-version</HeaderName><HeaderValue>2012-02-12</HeaderValue></Error>.<br />`

So far I figured out that the Azure PHP SDK might not be up to date according to this website: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal/

A guy on GitHub states that changing the `x-ms-version` header should solve the issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/288#issuecomment-74399273 Unfortunately I can't figure out on how to change the `x-ms-version` header within the Azure PHP SDK.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x-ms-version` header value is picked from `STORAGE_API_LATEST_VERSION` variable defined in `WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Resources.php` file. You may want to change that.